# String array to jSON array in Javascript?

Tags: json, string

I have a string file like this

```
["ORM.mp4","bla.bla","blaa.blaa"]
```

an any body tell me how can I convert it to array of jSON object.
I have tried various methods like `json.stringify()` then `json.parse()`etc. 
None of them worked.

*Any help would be highly appreciated!*

Comment: objects have keys and values. what are your keys, and what are your values?

Comment: can you plz give an example

Comment: Share your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var test = '["ORM.mp4","bla.bla","blaa.blaa"]';
var data = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(data );
```

You can use JSON.parse() for parsing json.

Comment: it gives me error Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Comment: I have just tried into console, it's running OK,  let me know to code. and witch **browser**.

Answer (score 1):

Use eval https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

```
 a = eval('["ORM.mp4","bla.bla","blaa.blaa"]')
 console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = ["ORM.mp4","bla.bla","blaa.blaa"].reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[i] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
```